# Pass d3 scroll/drag event to parent element if some conditions not met

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, scroll, touch

If opening the d3 example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9669633 with an touch device its not possible to scroll down the page while the touch point, to move the page around, is above the SVG (not on one of the circles).

If the touch point is outside the SVG area the page scrolls normally.

How could I achive normal scrolling in the SVG area too?

I want to achive scrolling up/down on touch device only if at least two fingers are used otherwise the event should be ignored and the browser should handle event.

On none touch devices its relatively easy to prevent, for instance, the zooming, by adding an filter function to the zoom handler and handling the "wheel" event. But for touch devices i am not getting it to function to allow the page scroll until my condition (2 fingers) are met.

Comment: You linked to the HTML version of the example, the SVG version can be found at https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9631744

Comment: The example doesn't matter. If you open the page with an touch device (tablet) try to move the page up/down while you touch inside the rectangle (white area, not directly on the circles). Its not possible! I'm trying to achieve the same behavior like a google maps (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction?hl=de). Normal page scroll is maintained, zooming/dragging should only be possible with two fingers.